# Encode string to an specified length using any algo

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, md5

Is there a way to compress/encode string to specified length(8/10 character).

I have a combination of secret key and a numeric value of 16 digit, and I want to create a unique id with combination of these both. which length should be between 8-12, and it should not change if combination is same.

Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's 16 decimal digits and your string can contain any characters, then sure. If you want ten characters out, then you'd need 40 different characters. 40<sup>10</sup> > 10<sup>16</sup>. Or for nine characters out, you need 60 different characters. 60<sup>9</sup> > 10<sup>16</sup>. E.g. some subset of the upper case letters, lower case letters, and digits (62 to choose 40 or 60 from). Then it is simply a matter of base conversion either way. Convert from base 10 to base 40 or 60, and then back.

Many languages already have Base-64 coding routines, which will get you to nine characters.

Eight is a problem, since you would need 100 characters (100<sup>8</sup> == 10<sup>16</sup>), and there are only 95 printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Actually I'm not that much expert in it, could you please share any reference link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a secure hash function, like sha512, and truncate the resulting hex string to the desired length.

If you want slightly more entropy, you can base64 encode it before truncating.

Comment: @AnujJPandey with a very high probability, yes. You won't get any lower collision probability without guaranteeing that there are no collisions, e.g. by sequentially numbering id's (which is a bad idea for other reasons).